# Removing a fragment android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, maps

So, ive two fragments in one parent fragment `MAPS` and `LIST`. `MAPS` is my maps fragment, `LIST` is normal listview. I have two buttons `MAPS_BUTTON` and `LIST_BUTTON`. When the main fragment is loaded the `MAPS` fragment is loaded by default, but when i click on list button, the `LIST` fragment is loaded where the `MAPS` was. My question is, whenever im on the `LIST` fragment, and i click on the `MAPS_BUTTON` the `LIST` fragment is not removed, it always stays there, hence i cannot see the maps fragment.

Can Anyone please help me  ?!

Following is my onclick code for both the buttons:

```
    map_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            lf= new ListFragment(bean, imgLoader);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(lf);
            //ft.addToBackStack("LIST");
            ft.commit();

            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

            Log.e("POPBACKSTACK: ", "POPBACKSTACK: "+getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());

        }
    });


    final Button list_view_button = (Button) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.list_view_button);
    list_view_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            map_button.setClickable(true);

            Fragment mf = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map);
            FragmentTransaction ftm = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ftm.remove(mf);
            ftm.addToBackStack("MAPS");
            ftm.commit();

            lf = new ListFragment(bean, imgLoader);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.maps_list_container, lf);
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: use view switcher concept your code,this concept may help you switch the your two fragments.

Comment: @prakash thanks a lot, i tried view switcher and it works like a charm !!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
public void removeCurrentFragment() {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();

    Fragment currentFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.fragment_container);

    setFragName("NONE");

    if (currentFrag != null) {
        setFragName(currentFrag.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    if (currentFrag != null) {
        transaction.remove(currentFrag);
    }

    transaction.commit();

}
```